# Unwind segue seems to deallocate my view objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm trying to pass an object using unwind segue. My button unwinds successfully, but all the objects in the view are reinitialized or something. I use `prepareForSegue` method to prepare my object successfully, but when I access the `viewController` in my destination segue (through an action button) all the objects are either reinitialized or not allocated.

I'm pretty new at this so any suggestions would be appreciated! Here's the code I'm stupefied with.

//prepareForSegue is called in my view controller i'm trying to unwind from.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ReturnInput"])
    {

        GLUPipeDataController *dataController;
        dataController.length = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:1.5];
        self.dataController = dataController;
        [self.dataController print];
    }
}
```

//this done is called in my destination view controller. It is linked in IB by control-draging the unbutton to the exit routine on the connections panel. I then updated the name of the unwind segue in the document outline.

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ReturnInput"])
    {
        GLUEditViewController *editController = [segue destinationViewController];

        if (editController.dataController)
        {
            self.dataController = editController.dataController;
            [self.dataController print];
            [[self tableView] reloadData];
        }
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ReturnInserts"]) {
        GLUEditInsertsViewController *editInsertController = [segue destinationViewController];
        if (editInsertController.listInserts) {
            self.dataController.listInserts = editInsertController.listInserts;
            [[self tableView] reloadData];
        }
    }
}
```

The call `[self.dataController print]` in `prepareForSegue` prints property. But the same call in the done method prints a newly initialized object.

Comment: How and when and where does `done:` get called?

Comment: The code you have in the done: method doesn't really make sense -- that code should be in the destination controller of the unwind segue, so segue.destinationViewController should be self. Also, it's unclear what you mean by "access the viewController in my destination segue (through an action button)" -- what view controller? What button action method?

Comment: Wow, super embarrassing! thanks rdelmar! I can't believe I missed that. I changed segue destinationViewController to segue sourceViewController and no problems.